# Good strategies for REST -> XML -> Core Data -> UITableView?

Tags: iphone, parsing, uitableview, core-data, libxml2

What are good practices for asynchronously pulling large amounts of XML from a RESTful service into a Core Data store, and from this store, populating a `UITableView` on the fly?

I'm thinking of using libxml2's `xmlParseChunk()` function to parse chunks of incoming XML and translate a node and its children into the relevant managed objects, as nodes come in.

At the same time that these XML nodes are turned into managed objects, I want to generate `UITableView` rows, in turn. Say, 50 rows at a time. Is this realistic?

In your experience, what do you do to accomplish this task, to maintain performance and handle, potentially, thousands of rows? Are there different, simpler approaches that work as well or better?

Comment: You might find http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/optimizing-loading-of-very-large-table.html useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, this is a pretty standard thing. The easiest solution is to do the loading in a background thread on one MOC, and have the UI running on the main thread with its own MOC. Whenever you get a chunk of data you want to have appear (say 50 entries), you have the background MOC`save:`.

Assuming you have the foreground MOC rigged to merge changes (via `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`) then whenever you save the background MOC the foreground MOC will get all of those changes. Assuming you are using NSFetchedResultsController it has delegate methods to cope with changes in its MOC, and if you are using Apple's sample code then you probably already have everything setup correctly.

In general CoreData is going to be faster than anything you roll yourself unless you really know what you are doing and are willing to spend a ton of time tuning for your specific case. The biggest thing you can do is make sure that slow things (like XML processing and synchronous flash I/O caused by `save:`) are not on the main thread blocking user interaction.

Comment: +1, but I'd love to pit http://sqlitepp.berlios.de/ against CoreData in an no-holds-barred death match to see which is faster

Comment: I absolutely can (and have) beaten CD on specific workloads using SQLite3 directly. But usually the amount of effort involved was obscene. I would have ended up with a better app by using CoreData, and then taking 1/3rd of the time I saved tuning other pieces of my app.

We don't write code in a vacuum. I have learned the hard way it is often better to give up some absolute theoretical performance and use the time savings to do make (larger) practical performance improvements to other pieces of an apps code. Obviously, the exact details vary project to project.

Comment: Is there any sample code that demonstrates the use of multiple MOCs with changes merged to one main MOC?

Answer (score 2):

Joe Hewitt (Facebook app developer) has release much of his code as open-source.  It is called [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20).  There is a class there that is great for fetching internet data and populating it into a table, without the need for the data beforehand.  The classes used for this are called [TTTableViewController](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTTableViewController.h) and [TTTableViewDataSource](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTTableViewDataSource.h).

From here, it would not be much of a stretch to store as CoreData, just subclass the classes as you see fit with the supplied hooks.

If you are worried about too much data, 50 at a time does sound reasonable.  These classes have a built in "More" button to help you out.

From the Three20 readme:

> **Internet-aware table view controllers**
>   TTTableViewController and
>   TTTableViewDataSource help you to
>   build tables which load their content
>   from the Internet. Rather than just
>   assuming you have all the data ready
>   to go, like UITableView does by
>   default, TTTableViewController lets
>   you communicate when your data is
>   loading, and when there is an error or
>   nothing to display. It also helps you
>   to add a "More" button to load the
>   next page of data, and optionally
>   supports reloading the data by shaking
>   the device.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear. I actually want to populate a Core Data store, which in turn populates a table view. It's not clear that this subclass solves this particular problem, if it pulls data cell by cell (which is not what I need to accomplish).

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned [RestKit](https://github.com/restkit/restkit) yet? My friends ... seriously, you have to check this out.  If you are doing anything with REST on iOS (and now on OS X) and particularly if you're wanting to work with Core Data ... PLEASE have a look at RestKit.  I've saved countless hours implementing some pretty complex data synchronization between a server and my Core Data models on iOS.  RestKit made it so damned easy, it almost makes you sick.

Comment: RestKit seems to struggle with XML - the XML parser it comes with has ARC errors when compiled on iOS 5. Overall it looks awesome though - particularly for straight JSON.